# PHP run function/logic when object property set

Tags: c#, php, class, oop

Every time I set a PHP object property, I want another property of the same object to be 20% of this value, or alternately put; I want to calculate the VAT at 20% of another property when I set the NetValue.

In C# it would be something like:

```
public class Product
{
    public decimal VAT { get; set; }
    private decimal _NetValue;
    public decimal NetValue { get { return _NetValue; } set { _NetValue = value; this.VAT = (value * 0.2M); } }
}
```

So back in PHP, when I do:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->NetValue = 10;
echo $product->VAT;
```

It should output: `2`.

How can I achieve this, since you can only set constants as object properties in PHP.  Is it possible?  I can't see how putting anything in the constructor can achieve this as mentioned in similar questions.

Comment: Would be that same in PHP as well, you are using a Setter in C# do the same in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) and more specifically [`__set`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) and [`__get`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set). Something like this:

```
<?php

class Product
{
    private $NetValue;
    private $VAT;

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
            if ($name == 'NetValue') {
                $this->VAT = 0.2 * $value;
            }
            $this->$name = $value;
        }
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
            return $this->$name;
        }
    }
}

$product = new Product();
$product->NetValue = 10;

echo($product->VAT);
```

Output will be:

```
2
```

Comment: Great! But... `__set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.`  Can I do this but have $NetValue and $VAT as public?

Comment: `The overloading methods are invoked when interacting with properties or methods that have not been declared or are not visible in the current scope.`. So you should change visibility of this properties to `protected` or `private`. But in any case you can access this properties with these `__set` and `__get` methods

Comment: Ah I see... they become visible when by other classes once you implement the `__set()` and `__get()` methods, since they can access the private ones.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with [Property overloading](http://php.net/manual/it/language.oop5.overloading.php), but i think that The Right Way™ to do this work is with a simple getter/setter.

```
class Product
{
    private $val;

    public function setNetValue($val)
    {
        $this->val = $val * 0.2;
    }

    public function getNetValue()
    {
        return $this->val;
    }
}

$product = new Product();
$product->setNetValue(10);
echo $product->getNetValue();
```

Here, encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty similiar in PHP

```
public class Product
{
    public $VAT;
    private $_NetValue;

    public function setNetValue($val) {
        $this->_NetValue = $val;
        $this->$VAT = $val * 0.2;
    }

    public function getNetValue() {
        return $this->_NetValue;
    }
}
$product = new Product();
$product->setNetValue(10);
echo 'Net Value = ' . $product->getNetValue();
echo 'VAT = ' . $product->VAT;
```

Result:

```
Net Value = 10
VAT = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

You must have to declare a member function equivalent to Setter property in c# to achieve this. Pass your value to that function where your logic is applied.